Nginx Proxy is much slower than Raw Laravel Octane Swoole, is that supposed to be the case?
I'm wondering, is this how it should be or is it too slow? Why is the proxy so much slower? Or everything is fine and I should calm down.
http://localhost/up - Nginx Proxy for Swoole
http://localhost:8000/up - Raw Laravel Octane Swoole
cepairda@DESKTOP-2PBE7CR:/mnt/c/Users/Alex$ wrk -t 16 -c 100 http://localhost/up
Running 10s test @ http://localhost/up
  16 threads and 100 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency    59.10ms   55.31ms 571.38ms   87.37%
    Req/Sec   123.41     62.70   252.00     53.29%
  19682 requests in 10.05s, 38.57MB read
Requests/sec:   1958.18
Transfer/sec:      3.84MB
cepairda@DESKTOP-2PBE7CR:/mnt/c/Users/Alex$ wrk -t 16 -c 100 http://localhost:8000/up
Running 10s test @ http://localhost:8000/up
  16 threads and 100 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency    46.94ms   49.04ms 458.27ms   91.58%
    Req/Sec   159.88     55.07   323.00     60.14%
  25557 requests in 10.10s, 50.40MB read
Requests/sec:   2531.07
Transfer/sec:      4.99MB
cepairda@DESKTOP-2PBE7CR:/mnt/c/Users/Alex$ wrk -t 16 -c 100 http://localhost/up
Running 10s test @ http://localhost/up
  16 threads and 100 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency    62.75ms   58.53ms 472.44ms   92.58%
    Req/Sec   114.63     34.76   240.00     75.73%
  18326 requests in 10.06s, 35.92MB read
Requests/sec:   1821.94
Transfer/sec:      3.57MB
cepairda@DESKTOP-2PBE7CR:/mnt/c/Users/Alex$ wrk -t 16 -c 100 http://localhost:8000/up
Running 10s test @ http://localhost:8000/up
  16 threads and 100 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency    54.35ms   56.76ms 488.40ms   91.73%
    Req/Sec   138.44     45.71   282.00     68.00%
  22133 requests in 10.06s, 43.65MB read
Requests/sec:   2200.10
Transfer/sec:      4.34MB

I am using the configuration setting from the octane documentation
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_tokens off;
    root /var/www/public;

    index index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location /index.php {
        try_files /not_exists @octane;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @octane;
    }

    #access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx-access.log;
    access_log off;
    #error_log  /var/log/nginx/nginx-error.log error;
    error_log  off;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    resolver 127.0.0.11;

    location @octane {
        set $suffix "";

        if ($uri = /index.php) {
            set $suffix ?$query_string;
        }

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header SERVER_PORT $server_port;
        proxy_set_header REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;

        proxy_pass http://taxi-app:8000$suffix;
    }
}

This is my docker-compose
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile
      target: production
#    user: ${UID}:${GID}
    restart: always
    container_name: taxi-app
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    secrets:
      - production_env
    volumes:
      - app-storage:/var/www/storage
      #- ./app-public:/var/www/public
    depends_on:
      postgres-db:
        condition: service_healthy
      redis:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - taxi-postgres-db-network
      - taxi-webserver-network
      - taxi-redis-network
    healthcheck:
      test: curl -s http://localhost:8000/up >/dev/null || exit 1
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    #extra_hosts:
    #  host.docker.internal: host-gateway
  webserver:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile
      target: webserver
    #image: nginx:1.27-alpine
    container_name: taxi-webserver
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - app-storage:/var/www/storage
      - ./docker/local/nginx/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
      - ./storage/logs/nginx/:/var/log/nginx/
    ports:
      - 80:80
    networks:
      - taxi-webserver-network
    healthcheck:
      test: curl -s http://localhost/up >/dev/null || exit 1
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
  postgres-db:
    image: postgis/postgis:16-3.5-alpine
    container_name: taxi-postgres-db
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_DATABASE}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - taxi-postgres-db-network
    healthcheck:
      test: pg_isready -U ${DB_USERNAME} -d ${DB_DATABASE}
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
  redis:
    image: redis:7.4.1-alpine
    restart: always
    container_name: taxi-redis
    command:
      - 'redis-server'
      - '--requirepass ${REDIS_PASSWORD}'
    volumes:
      - redis-data:/data
    networks:
      - taxi-redis-network
    healthcheck:
      test: redis-cli ping
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

networks:
  taxi-webserver-network:
    driver: overlay
    name: taxi-webserver-network
  taxi-postgres-db-network:
    driver: overlay
    name: taxi-postgres-db-network
  taxi-redis-network:
    driver: overlay
    name: taxi-redis-network

volumes:
  app-storage:
    driver: local
    name: taxi-app-storage
  postgres-data:
    driver: local
    name: taxi-postgres-data
  redis-data:
    driver: local
    name: taxi-redis-data

secrets:
  production_env:
    file: ./app/.production-env


Usually nginx solves the tasks of SSL termination and static content serving. Being used the way you've shown in your test case, as just an extra proxying layer, it can't be faster than the backend app itself. I also doubt it will be serving the static content at all since you mount your app-storage volume as /var/www/storage and set the root as /var/www/public. Moreover, I've come across some less-than-ideal nginx configuration examples in the official documentation for various software products, but this one is really awful.

I won't believe it until I find the officially recommended configuration myself. Here is the alternative nginx configuration that at least gets rid of the if directive in location context and no longer requires the resolver to be defined, while retaining all the original functionality: https://termbin.com/3sgm

@IvanShatsky Thank you very much. I see you are from Odessa, I am from Kharkov, if you are well versed in nginx and docker, can I consult with you?

Email me ivan(dot)shatsky(at)gmail(dot)com. And yes, a 20% difference isn't a normal thing. Here is slightly more optimized nginx config: https://termbin.com/o73gu
